# The probability that people select identical balls: two-person case is simple, but more-than-2-person case is complicated.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are $n$ distinct balls. There are $p$ people, and the $i$th person selects $q_i$ distinct balls from these $n$ distinct balls.

The question is: what is the probability that $q_0$ balls are exactly identical in every $q_i$ distinct balls which the $i$th person selects ($i = 1, 2, \dots, p$).

(Without loss of generality you may assume $q_0 \le q_1 \le q_2 \le \dots \le q_p <n$.)

**Two-person Case** This case is simple and easy. Now, we first consider this simple two-person case: there are two persons, Tom and Jack. Tom selects $q_1$ distinct balls from these $n$ distinct balls; In the same way, Jack selects $q_2$ distinct balls from these $n$ distinct balls. The probability that $q_0$ balls are exactly identical in Tom's $q_1$ balls and Jack's $q_2$ balls equals 
$${Prob}_2=\binom{n}{q_1}\binom{q_1}{q_0}\binom{n-q_1}{q_2-q_0}/\binom{n}{q_1}/\binom{n}{q_2}$$
The thought behind the formula ${Prob}_2$ is: Tom selects $q_1$ balls first. Then Jack selects $q_0$ balls from these $q_1$ balls. After that, Jack selects $q_2-q_0$ balls from the rest $n-q_1$ balls.

**More-than-two-person Case** I feel this case is difficult. I try solving it by the following thought: 
Step 1) Select $q_0$ balls from $n$ balls;
Step 2) Each person selects $q_i−q_0$ balls from the rest $n−q_0$ balls.

The formula is 
$${Prob}_p=\binom{n}{q_0}\binom{n-q_0}{q_1-q_0}\binom{n-q_0}{q_2-q_0}\binom{n-q_0}{q_3-q_0}...\binom{n-q_0}{q_p-q_0}/\binom{n}{q_1}/\binom{n}{q_2}/\binom{n}{q_3}/.../\binom{n}{q_p}$$
Unfortunately, this formula ${Prob}_p$ is wrong because ${Prob}_p \neq {Prob}_2$ when $p=2$.

Thus, the question is how to solve the general case of this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Maths.SE! Please read [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: @Lord_Farin Thank you very much. I have reworded my question.

Answer (score 1):

*Think* about the problem.  First, to have the set of balls the same, you need the same number of balls selected.  You have not provided any information on how each person chooses the number of balls they will select.  Then each person has to choose those $q_0$ balls and $q_i-q_0$ from the rest.

Comment: Thank you very much. Follow your thinking, my answer is: $$\binom{n}{q_0}\binom{n-q_0}{q_1-q_0}\binom{n-q_0}{q_2-q_0}...\binom{n-q_0}{q_p-q_0}/\binom{n}{q_1}/\binom{n}{q_2}/.../\binom{n}{q_p}$$ Is it correct?

Comment: You should not just state an answer, you should show the logic that lead you there.  It makes it much easier to give useful comment.  So "the 0th person selects $q_0$ balls.   The next selects $q_1$ balls, which must include the set of $q_0$. There are ${n-q_0 \choose q_1-q_0}$ ways to do that." and so on.  I don't think you want the factor $n \choose q_0$

Comment: My logic is: first select $q_0$ balls from $n$ balls; then each person selects $q_i-q_0$ balls from the rest $n-q_0$ balls. But I find the answer may be wrong regardless of the factor  $\binom{n}{q_0}$. I know the ground truth of the two-person case: Person 1 selects $q_1$ balls, and Person 2 selects $q_2$ balls. First Person 1 selects $q_1$ balls, then Person 2 selects $q_0$ balls from these $q_1$ balls, after that, Person 2 selects $q_2-q_0$ balls from the rest $n-q_1$ balls. Thus, the answer is $$\binom{n}{q_1}\binom{q_1}{q_0}\binom{n-q_1}{q_2-q0}/\binom{n}{q_1}/\binom{n}{q_2}$$